# Windows Phone 8 project templates for VS2015

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015

I have installed the Windows Phone 8 developer tools and it comes with default VS2012 express for Windows Phone. But I have already VS2015 set up in my pc.

I am not seeing windows phone project templates from new project dialog VS2015. Am I missing something here?[image]

Comment: And what happens when you click that big old sign saying you should download the templates and tools?

Comment: run the VS2015 setup, select modify and select the Win8/Phone 8.1 tools

Comment: @Will - It asks me to download the Windows Phone developer tools again and install...

Comment: Sounds like a bad install.  I'd reinstall.